# Upgrade zsh on red hat 5 x86_64

Tags: rhel, zsh, package-management

My machine is running RHEL 5 x86_64
I'm facing a [problem with `oh-my-zsh`](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/issues/399)

The `zsh` version on my machine is

```
zsh --version
zsh 4.2.6 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
```

There are no upgrades available via `yum`. How can I install a newer version of `zsh`?

I've tried to look for `rpms` on the internet but they're for fedora or other distros.

```
➜  src  sudo rpm -ivh zsh-5.0.2-1.fc18.x86_64.rpm  
warning: zsh-5.0.2-1.fc18.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 signature: NOKEY, key ID de7f38bd
error: Failed dependencies:
    libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.11)(64bit) is needed by zsh-5.0.2-1.fc18.x86_64
    libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit) is needed by zsh-5.0.2-1.fc18.x86_64
    libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.15)(64bit) is needed by zsh-5.0.2-1.fc18.x86_64
    libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.7)(64bit) is needed by zsh-5.0.2-1.fc18.x86_64
    libtinfo.so.5()(64bit) is needed by zsh-5.0.2-1.fc18.x86_64
    rpmlib(FileDigests) <= 4.6.0-1 is needed by zsh-5.0.2-1.fc18.x86_64
    rpmlib(PayloadIsXz) <= 5.2-1 is needed by zsh-5.0.2-1.fc18.x86_64
➜  src  sudo rpm -ivh zsh-4.3.17-1.fu2012.x86_64.rpm 
warning: zsh-4.3.17-1.fu2012.x86_64.rpm: Header V4 DSA signature: NOKEY, key ID 42d68235
error: Failed dependencies:
    libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.11)(64bit) is needed by zsh-4.3.17-1.fu2012.x86_64
    libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit) is needed by zsh-4.3.17-1.fu2012.x86_64
    libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.15)(64bit) is needed by zsh-4.3.17-1.fu2012.x86_64
    libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.7)(64bit) is needed by zsh-4.3.17-1.fu2012.x86_64
    libgdbm.so.3()(64bit) is needed by zsh-4.3.17-1.fu2012.x86_64
    libtinfo.so.5()(64bit) is needed by zsh-4.3.17-1.fu2012.x86_64
    rpmlib(FileDigests) <= 4.6.0-1 is needed by zsh-4.3.17-1.fu2012.x86_64
    rpmlib(PayloadIsXz) <= 5.2-1 is needed by zsh-4.3.17-1.fu2012.x86_64
```

It appears that I can't install the latest version of glibc either :|

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [comment on github](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/issues/399#issuecomment-1305256), someone says they used the zsh 4.3.10 from CentOS. I did the same, using the src.rpm from [CentOS 6](http://vault.centos.org/6.3/os/Source/SPackages/zsh-4.3.10-5.el6.src.rpm). The RPM built fine with no modifications needed. Here's the RPMs, the source, debuginfo, and html RPMs are in the same directory if you need them:

- http://mmckinst.fedorapeople.org/one-offs/zsh/zsh-4.3.10-5.el5.i386.rpm
- http://mmckinst.fedorapeople.org/one-offs/zsh/zsh-4.3.10-5.el5.x86_64.rpm

I built the RPM using [mock](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Projects/Mock).

Comment: `I'm using ZSH version 5.0.2. The minimum required version for Powerlevel10k is 5.1.` I can't find a updated package? do you have a reference to >5.1`rpm` package? I tried to install `rpm -U zsh-5.5.1-6.el8_1.2.x86_64.rpm` [from](https://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=zsh(x86-64)), but It's giving error `warning: zsh-5.5.1-6.el8_1.2.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID 8483c65d: NOKEY
error: Failed dependencies:
 libgdbm.so.6()(64bit) is needed by 
 libm.so.6(GLIBC_2.23)(64bit)  libncursesw.so.6()(64bit)
 libtinfo.so.6()(64bit) `

Answer (score 0):

If you *really* must run a newer version of zsh, I'd start with the source RPM for RHEL 5 (o even RHEL 6), unpack it, replace the source in it by the latest, and build your own. Fedora has [instrucions](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_create_an_RPM_package), which should be mostly applicable to RHEL, which descends from Fedora.

Just be sure to check that the patches still apply, perhaps look for the latest Fedora source RPM and create your RHEL rpm by stitching its sources and patches in.

Note that you are taking over the responsibility to keep your package up to date and secured.